# Why doesn't set -e work when exporting a variable with a value from a failed command substitution?

Tags: bash

I want to exit this script before the `echo "after VAR=$VAR"` line when `fails-sometimes.sh` exits with non 0 code.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eux
echo "before"
export VAR=$(./fails-sometimes.sh)
echo "after VAR=$VAR"
```

The "-e" option here doesn't stop the script.
How should I write this?

Comment: `set -e` is prone to **many** surprising effects -- it is by no means universally considered good practice. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- and, on `set -u`, [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112).

Comment: BTW, as an aside, all-caps names are specified by POSIX for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use. Since setting a regular shell variable will automatically overwrite any like-named environment variable, this convention applies across both. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -e` doesn't work here because the `export` command still succeed. This is one of several examples where `set -e` does what it's supposed to, but [not really what you'd expect](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

In general it's a good practice to avoid using `export`, `local`, and similar assignments together with command substitutions, as they suppress the exit code of the substitution. Prefer to [split it into two separate commands](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155):

```
export VAR
VAR=$(./fails-sometimes.sh)
```

Written like this the second command will fail (and therefore exit the script due to `set -e`) if the command substitution fails.